# C++ pthread synchronization and multiple wake up for thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, wakeup

a question about C++ thread synchronization.
We suppose that have 2 pthreads: Thread1 and Thread2.

- Thread1 is engaged in its task and, in some cases, he must notify the update of the state to the Thread2.
- Thread2 is engaged in its work of extracting data from a synchronized queue. So, the Thread2 can sleep if the queue is empty.

How can I wake up the Thread2 on two conditions:

- New message notification in the queue;

  or
- status change of the Thread1

practical code-examples are welcome

Comment: What did you code so far?

Comment: nothing, I'm designing the architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, make Thread1 insert the status change notification as a task in the queue where it can be consumed by Thread2. If the notification has higher priority than regular work tasks, allow Thread1 to insert it in the queue ahead of other tasks, making it the next one to be consumed.

Comment: ok this might be a quick solution to achieve my goal ...
But how do you accomplish that which I have described in my question?

Comment: I'd say this is how you achieve the goal you describe... Is there any additional requirement that makes this solution unsuitable?

Comment: No.. Surely I'll use your suggestion ... but I was curious about how you can implement that described in my question .. just curious for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you also use the same queue(but different command code) to notify thread2? Thread2 just waiting for any data in the queue in blocking mode, for each new message, check it's for status update or data, and do corresponding actions.

Comment: ok this might be a quick solution to achieve my goal ...
But how do you accomplish that which I have described in my question?

Comment: You need to define the messages thread2 receives: seems you need two kinds of messages. You may have a message header to identify which kind of message it is. Thread2 first check the header then do corresponding processing.